# Querying the elastic search before inserting into it

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

i am using spring boot application to load messages into elastic search. i have a use case where i need to query the elastic search data , get some id value and populate it in elastic search json document before inserting it into elastic search

Querying the elastic search before insertion . Will this be expensive ? If yes is there some other way to approach this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) to do it in one step.

But otherwise it shouldn't be slow if you do it in two steps (get + update). It depends on many things - how often you do it, how much data is transferred, etc.